# MIme types not correct when using Go server

Tags: html, css, http, go

I'm learning how to make a backend with Go and I made a simple server that just loads a login page. When the page is loaded the external css and js files are not being loaded. When I looked to see what was wrong in the console I got this message "Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "`http://localhost:8081/login/css/bootstrap.min.css`". " I get this error for all the css and js files included in the html file.

Here is the Go code:

```
package main

import(


    "net/http"

)





func loginFunc(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){

     http.ServeFile(w, r, "index.html")
}

func main(){

    http.HandleFunc("/login/", loginFunc);
    http.ListenAndServe(":8081", nil);
}
```

Here's the html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">

        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



        <style type="text/css">


            .topSpace{
                margin-top: 15%;
            }
            #mods{
                background-color: #3AC578;
                padding-top: 1.5%;
                padding-bottom: 1.5%;
                box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px #888888;
                border-radius: 10px;

            }





        </style>



    </head>

    <body>

        <div class="container-fluid">

            <div class="row topSpace" id="content">
                <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4"></div>

                <div class="col-xs-3 cod-md-3" id="mods">
                    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                      <div class="form-group">

                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="qlid"  placeholder="Quicklook ID" maxlength="8">
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">

                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                          <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd"  placeholder="Password" maxlength="16">
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <div class=" col-sm-offset-1 form-inline">
                          <div class="checkbox">
                            <label>
                              <input id="chkbx" type="checkbox"> Remember me
                            </label>
                          </div>



                          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary col-sm-offset-4" id="submitBtn">Sign in</button>

                      </div>

                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hmm, the code you set up doesn't include serving static-files directories like `/css` or `/js` at all. To do it from Go, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14086063/serve-homepage-and-static-content-from-root) suggests `http.Handle("/css/", http.StripPrefix("/css/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./css/"))))`. It's also common to put nginx in front of your Go server to handle tasks like static file serving.

Comment: How would I put nginx in front of my Go server? I'm new the http game.

Comment: You could also just use one of the already available CDNs for Bootstrap and JQuery, unless you need to serve custom resources.

http://www.bootstrapcdn.com
https://code.jquery.com/

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use nginx, it's extremely optimized for that kind of tasks, and it is the recommended way to use https.

An example conf is:

```
server {
    listen       0.0.0.0:80;
    charset utf-8;

    location /s/  {
        alias /path/to/app/static/;
        autoindex off;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_set_header        Host             $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        # where 9020 is the port your go app is running on
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9020; 
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
}
```

references:

- personal experience.
- http://nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/serving-static-content/
- [Nginx -- static file serving confusion with root & alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10631933/nginx-static-file-serving-confusion-with-root-alias)