# Prepoluting index page before mux Handle call

Tags: go, gorilla, go-http

I recently built a small blog website for testing purposes and I'm a little stuck with this problem while writing the server in Go. I have all the files of the website inside the `static` folder, which is also the root for the `http.FileServer` given to `mux.Handle`. Everything works fine, except that I need to pre-polutate the data of the index page with the data of the articles.

If I build the index page with `mux.HandleFunc` and call the index that way I lose all the CSS format because, of course, mux does not know where to find that since he has no root `fs` to check into.

So my question basically is: is it possible to pre-populate the index page with some data (e.g. reading the data from a json file and parse it with `template.ParseFiles`, for example) and still use `mux.Handle` as mount point of the website?

```
package main

import (
    "mywebsite/handlers"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {

    var mux = http.NewServeMux()
    mux.Handle("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("static")))

    /*This throws panic: pattern "/" (registered at /home/nicola/Desktop/mywebsite/main.go:12) conflicts with pattern "/" (registered at /home/nicola/Desktop/mywebsite/main.go:11):
    / matches the same requests as / */
    mux.HandleFunc("/", handlers.IndexHandler)

    err := http.ListenAndServe(":3345", mux)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

Thank you so much for any hint!

Comment: Keep your static files under `/static`, but move the index page somewhere else, and use a template to generate the page.

Comment: I thought about that, but then again the `index` page would not be called on first landing on the website. For example, if I use like `mux.HandleFunc("/index", indexHandler...)` it would be called only by going to `localhost:port/index`. The real root would still be managed by `mux.Handle("/", fs)`, which server the file system with `static` as root.

Comment: please check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14086063/serve-homepage-and-static-content-from-root
I think you are trying to do the same

Comment: "Everything works fine, except that I need to pre-polutate the data of the index page with the data of the articles." or, you could build an API endpoint with Go that was called by Javascript code in the static assets to retrieve the article data and populate the page.  Many websites are built that way.  If you were trying to build a real static blog I'd point you towards something like https://github.com/gohugoio/hugo that way you don't have to have a program running just to generate content from data

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but tbf I was trying to avoid using JS. The project is really simple and it's a sort of challenge for me to build it entirely in Go, without falling back to Vue or something!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I somehow solved like this. Moved css into a separate directory called `css`.
So basically my workspace is now something like this:

```
.
├── blogposts
│   ├── 1.html
│   └── 2.html
├── go.mod
├── handlers
│   ├── contactshandler.go
│   ├── indexhandler.go
│   ├── projectshandler.go
│   └── readerhandler.go
├── main.go
└── static
    ├── components
    │   ├── navigation-links1.css
    │   └── navigation-links1.html
    ├── contacts.html
    ├── css
    │   ├── 404.css
    │   ├── contacts.css
    │   ├── index.css
    │   ├── projects.css
    │   └── style.css
    ├── index.html
    ├── package.json
    ├── projects.html
    └── public
        └── external
            ├── 1f3eb.svg
            └── 1f44b.svg
```

Then routed  the mux like this

```
    mux.Handle("/css/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("static")))
    mux.Handle("/components/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("static")))
    mux.Handle("/public/external/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("static")))
    
    mux.HandleFunc("/", handlers.IndexHandler)
    mux.HandleFunc("/projects", handlers.ProjectsHandler)
    mux.HandleFunc("/contacts", handlers.ContactsHandler)
    mux.HandleFunc("/read/", handlers.ReaderHandler)
```

So basically `mux` now handles three different `fs`, one for each folder inside `static` serving CSS and other graphic stuff.
Not the most beautiful job, but for this little website it works fine!